# Service Principal added as unknown in keyvault access policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, service-principal

I want to add Service Principal to Azure Keyvault access policies.

I tried with below command

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'kvevalmock' -ObjectId '23erer-ed58-4ead-w34d-1ete23w3yofa' -PermissionsToSecrets @("get","list","set","delete","backup","restore","recover","purge") -PermissionsToKeys @("decrypt","encrypt","unwrapKey","wrapKey","verify","sign","get","list","update","create","import","delete","backup","restore","recover","purge") -BypassObjectIdValidation
```

Command gets executed but in keyvault access policies, Service principal is not listed in Application section. SP gets added as Unknown.
Due to this issue, keyvault secrets creation throw forbidden access error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the parameter `-ObjectId`, you should provide object id of the service principal(enterprise app) but not the object id of the registered app.

First go to your registered app, I guess you copy the object id in this page:

[image]

Click the "**Managed application in local directory**" which in red box in screenshot above to go to the service principal(enterprise app). And then copy the object of the app, use the object id in your command.
[image]

Comment: Hi Hury Shen, Thank you. The solution worked perfectly. Is there any way to get that objectId value dynamically?

Comment: @Amruta Could you please provide more details of your requirement ? What do you want to query for objectId based on ? Based on app name ?

Comment: yes...can I retrieve ObjectId based on app name?

Comment: @Amruta Yes, you can retrieve ObjectId based on app name by `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "appName"`. But if multiple apps have the same name, this command will response a list of all the apps.